# On the stationary density of an autoregressive model of order 2

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, autoregressive

Consider a stochastic process $\{X_t, t = 1, 2, \ldots\}$ following a stationary AR(2) model  $$X_t = \theta_1 X_{t-1} +  \theta_2 X_{t-2} +e_t,$$ where $e_t \thicksim N(0, \sigma^2)$.

I want to find the stationary density for this model and then assign it to $X_1$ in order to completely specify my model but I can't find it as I would do with an AR(1).

**The attempt:**

To obtain the marginal distribution required for a stationary model we set  $\sigma_X^2 = \mathbb{V}(X_t) = \mathbb{V}(X_{t-1})$.  From the recursive equation defining the AR process we obtain

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\sigma_X^2 = \mathbb{V}(X_t) 
&= \mathbb{V}(\theta_1 X_{t-1} + \theta_2X_{t-2}+ e_t) \\[6pt]
&= \theta_1^2 \mathbb{V}(X_{t-1}) + \theta_2^2 \mathbb{V}(X_{t-2}) +2 \theta_1 \theta_2 Cov (X_{t-1}, X_{t-2})+\mathbb{V}(e_t) \\[6pt]
&=  \sigma_X^2 (\theta_1^2 + \theta_2^2) + \sigma^2 +2 \theta_1 \theta_2 Cov (X_{t-1}, X_{t-2}) \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

In the AR(1) case I could easily isolate $\sigma^2_X$ in terms of known quantities to obtain the distribution to assign to $X_1$ to make the process stationary but in the AR(2) case I am left with a pesky $Cov (X_{t-1}, X_{t-2})$, how should one proceed to solve this issue?

Comment: One approach would be to write the model as $x_t = (1-\theta_1L - \theta_2L^2)^{-1} \epsilon_t$, then you can solve the problem if you can invert the lagpolynomial.